# Provide-Inject return multi-layer object in vue3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm trying to use provide-inject in my own project, but when I use inject() to get the provide object, the value returned by inject().value is an RefImpl Object, which means I need to get the value by using inject().value.value

In App.vue

```
setup() {
  let userName = ref("Example");
  provide("userName", userName);
}
```

In the login component

```
var appUserName = inject("userName");
```

```
console.log(appUserName, appUserName.value, appUserName.value.value)
```

The console output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVagV.png)

In app.vue, I've change the definition of param 'userName' from let to const, but still no effort.

```
setup() {
    const userName = ref("Example");
    provide("userName", userName);
}
```

And I check the provide() of this param, only in the app.vue I use provide("userName"), which means there is no multiply provide() for this param.

Comment: There is some code in your component that set `userName.value = ref("admin")` because I see the "admin" value in your console log

Comment: Yes, after login I will set appUserName.value identical to the name used for login 
```if (response.status) {appUserName.value = userName; }
```

Comment: Check that code. It should be `appUserName.value = 'admin'` not `appUserName.value = ref("admin")`

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem. I forgot the userName is a ref() type, in the code it should be ```appUserName.value = userName.value```.

Answer (score 0):

Thank @Duannx solve my problem.
The problem occurred by forgetting the type of param `userName` is ref() type, in code it should be `appUserName.value = userName.value;`. In the original code, I write as `appUserName.value = userName` and cause this problem.